# Maintaining multiple unrelated histories in one git repository

Tags: git, version-control

My use case: I want to create several small example programs, and store them all in an `examples/` repo. When someone checkouts `examples/a`, I would like them to be able to run `git log` and see only the commits relevant to `a/` without the large number of unrelated commits for `b/` `c/` `d/` and `e/`.

I understand that `git submodule` or `git subtree` can do this, but those all require separate repos and I don't think it is worth creating 50 different repos of one or two files each. I would like them to all live in one repo, but maintain different histories. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. You can fetch or create any history structures you like in a repository. Easiest way to make a new empty branch in `examples` is

```
git worktree add examples/new $(git commit-tree -mstub.message `git mktree <&-`)
```

and amend the stub commit with your first set of content.

I also use this regularly to carry "incorporated submodules", utility code that's always required but shared with other projects, the `git submodule` command is distinctly optional but it's easy to finagle it into working with this setup, just tell it you've already cloned the upstream module, for e.g. a "utils" history carried in the `utils` branch I'll

```
git submodule init utils
git worktree add utils :utils
```

on clone, with

```
[submodule "utils"]
    path = utils
    url = ./
    branch = utils
```

in `.gitmodules` and that's the machinery all set up.

Comment: Thank you, works great! Unfortunately seems like Github does not support it though.

Comment: Cloners need to use the two-command sequence I gave instead of `git submodule update --init --recursive`, the submodule history's a perfectly ordinary branch you already have, you could ask about whatever specific thing you're referring to.